# Solve this simple problem of Simplification

Tags: arithmetic

Simplify
$14-\frac{21}{7}+4*2$

Answer given is $3$ but mine is $19$. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not written as $14-(21/7+4*2)$ in your book?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is as You asked, $14-21/7+4*2$, Then the answer is 19
If the question is $14-(21/7+4*2)$, Then the answer is 3.